# pspp 0.10.2 upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, software-installation

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 (and an amateur) --and installed PSPP from the Software Center. PSPP 0.7.9 was available there. I then checked the software developer site (http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/pspp) and learned that a newer version is available, 0.10.2. I used

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade pspp
```

which appeared to upgrade (I don't know how to capture the lines of actions that transpired). I restarted, and then opened PSPP, which is still version 0.7.9.

How do I upgrade to 0.10.2?

I'm happy to provide more information, and I'll probably need guidance on how to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pspp` package in the official Ubuntu repositories for Ubuntu 14.04 is indeed rather outdated. As mentioned in https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/pspp-users/2016-06/msg00005.html, you can upgrade `pspp` to version 0.10.2 using the [PSPP Stable Releases PPA](https://launchpad.net/~adamzammit/+archive/ubuntu/pspp) by Adam Zammit:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adamzammit/pspp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```